# Magento V2 API Problem

Tags: magento2, error, api

I am developing a program, using `Magento V2 SOAP API`, but I can not find how to Create Product, the API only provide me `DeleteEntity, GetList Entity, and Save Entity`.
I have tried to use `catalogProductRepositoryV1Save`, but got an exception `"Can not save product". But I can get all product details using GetList APP`.

anyone can help me? code as below:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(mservice.InnerChannel))
                {
                    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

                    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;                  

                    CatalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest x = new CatalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest();

                    var t = new CatalogDataProductInterface();
                    t.attributeSetId = 4;
                    t.name = "Jason Test";
                    t.price = 456;
                    //t.priceSpecified = false;
                    t.sku = "34567890";
                    t.visibility = 1;
                    t.weight = 3;
                    t.typeId = "Simple";
                    t.status = 1;
                    t.createdAt = t.updatedAt = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                    t.productLinks = null;
                    t.attributeSetIdSpecified = true;
                    t.extensionAttributes = null;
                    t.mediaGalleryEntries = null;
                    t.id = 0;

                    var m = new FrameworkAttributeInterface[3];
                    //var w = new CatalogDataProductExtensionInterface();


                    // 1st Attribute
                    m[0] = new FrameworkAttributeInterface { attributeCode = "C1", value = "I3" };
                    // 2nd attribute
                    m[1] = new FrameworkAttributeInterface { attributeCode = "O2", value = "W8" };
                    m[2] = new FrameworkAttributeInterface { attributeCode = "S3", value = "15" };

                    t.customAttributes = m;
                    x.product = t;
                    var DEST = mservice.catalogProductRepositoryV1Save(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

My working example for create product in M2 by SOAP
You should djust create token in BO and add it in header like Authorization: Bearer

```
$wsdl = "http://magento2-ce.local/soap/default?services=catalogProductRepositoryV1";
$xml_post_string = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://magento2-ce.local/soap/default?services=catalogProductRepositoryV1">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
            <product>
                <sku>1005001</sku>
                <name>TEST PRODUCT</name>
                <attributeSetId>4</attributeSetId>
                <price>19.99</price>
                <status>1</status>
                <visibility>4</visibility>
                <typeId>simple</typeId>
                <weight>1</weight>
            </product>
        </def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Authorization: Bearer wcawo83o8098wr67hj0msjgkxsj1qpuq",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen("soap.xml", "w");
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thanks goral, I have create the correct token, and I can fetch product's detail,  but I still got an exception while I want to Create a New Product.

Comment: Please provide result of var_dump($result);